# uisearchbar issue when scopebar is hide and show

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisegmentedcontrol, uisearchcontroller

[image: this issue occurs if i forcefully show the scope bar to render]
while presenting the search controller i am setting the showScopeBar property to hide or show the scope bar

```
- (void)willPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    // do something before the search controller is presented
    NSMutableArray *scopeArray = @[@"All"].mutableCopy;
    UISearchBar *searchBar =_searchController.searchBar;
    if (![labelDepartmentSelection.text isEqualToString:@"Department"]) {
        [scopeArray addObject:@"Department"];
    }
    if (![labelJobSelection.text isEqualToString:@"Job"]) {
        [scopeArray addObject:@"Job"];
    }
    searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = scopeArray;

    searchBar.showsScopeBar = scopeArray.count>1;
    [searchBar layoutIfNeeded];
    NSArray *subviews = searchBar.subviews;
    if([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue]>=7.0) {
        //Get search bar with scope bar to reappear after search keyboard is dismissed
        UIView *scopeBar = [subviews.firstObject subviews].firstObject;
        [scopeBar setHidden:NO];
        CGRect frame = scopeBar.frame;
        frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y = 64.0;
        scopeBar.frame = frame;
    }
    [searchBar layoutSubviews];

    [searchBar sizeToFit];
    [serviceOptionTableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(scopeArray.count>1?44:0, 0, 0, 0)];

    serviceOptionTableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar;
}
```

and when i simply hide and show the scope bar base on the scope titles i want it giet distorted 
here is the case for this

```
- (void)willPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    // do something before the search controller is presented
    NSMutableArray *scopeArray = @\[@"All"\].mutableCopy;
    UISearchBar *searchBar =_searchController.searchBar;
    if (!\[labelDepartmentSelection.text isEqualToString:@"Department"\]) {
        \[scopeArray addObject:@"Department"\];
    }
    if (!\[labelJobSelection.text isEqualToString:@"Job"\]) {
        \[scopeArray addObject:@"Job"\];
    }
    searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = scopeArray;

    searchBar.showsScopeBar = scopeArray.count>1;

    \[serviceOptionTableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(scopeArray.count>1?44:0, 0, 0, 0)\];

}
```

this is the image of case 2

Comment: were you able to fix this?

Comment: actually i found that updating the scopes of uisearch bar at run time was creating this issue..

Answer (score 0):

The issue should fix itself if you remove the line:

```
searchBar.showsScopeBar = scopeArray.count>1;
```

Setting the showScopeBar property has a weird effect for some reason. Removing it allows the default animation behaviour without any issues.